# docker with ansible wait for database

Tags: docker, ansible

I try to deploy docker with ansible. I have one docker database container, and in other container is my web app, and I try to link this two container. The problem is that database container didn't have a time to configure itself and a web container is already started. My ansible playbook look something like:

```
...
- name: run mysql in docker container
  docker:
    image: "mysql:5.5"
    name: database
    env: "MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=password"
    state: running

- name: run application containers
  docker:
    name: "application"
    image: "myapp"
    ports:
      - "8080:8080"
    links:
      - "database:db"
    state: running
```

How to determine if database is start? I try with wait_for module, but that didn't work. I don't want to set timeout, it's not good option for me.

Answer (score 15):

**wait_for** does not work for the MySQL docker container because it only checks that the port is connectable (which is true straight away for the Docker container). However, **wait_for** does not check that the service inside the container listens the port and sends responses to the client.

This is how I am waiting in the ansible playbook for the MySQL service becoming fully operational inside the Docker container:

```
- name: Start MySQL container
  docker:
    name: some-name
    image: mysql:latest
    state: started
    ports:
    - "8306:3306" # it's important to expose the port for waiting requests
    env:
        MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: "{{ mysql_root_password }}"

- template: mode="a+rx,o=rwx" src=telnet.sh.j2 dest=/home/ubuntu/telnet.sh

# wait while MySQL is starting
- action: shell /home/ubuntu/telnet.sh
  register: result
  until: result.stdout.find("mysql_native_password") != -1
  retries: 10
  delay: 3
```

And the telnet.sh.j2 is

```
#!/bin/bash -e

telnet localhost 8306 || true
```

Comment: Any reason why you are running the telnet command in a separate script?

Answer (score 11):

To avoid the sh and I don't normally have telnet installed...

```
- name: Wait for database to be available
  shell: docker run --rm --link mysql:mysql mysql sh -c 'mysql -h"$MYSQL_PORT_3306_TCP_ADDR" -P"$MYSQL_PORT_3306_TCP_PORT" -uroot -p{{mysql_password}} || true'
  register: result
  until: result.stderr.find("Can't connect to MySQL") == -1
  retries: 10
  delay: 3
```

Comment: This works well for me and I like that it avoids a script or telnet. I am using a variation with `mysqladmin ping` and `docker exec`. I use the `command` module with `docker exec {{ container_name }} mysqladmin ping` and then `until` becomes `result.rc == 0`.

Answer (score 7):

As [etrubenok said](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34668284/1031434):

> wait_for does not work for the MySQL docker container because it only checks that the port is connectable (which is true straight away for the Docker container). However, wait_for does not check that the service inside the container listens the port and sends responses to the client.

Using [Andy Shinn's suggestion of FreshPow's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37930169/1031434), you can wait without needing a shell script or telnet:

```
- name: Wait for mariadb
  command: >
    docker exec {{ container|quote }}
    mysqladmin ping -u{{ superuser|quote }} -p{{ superuser_password|quote }}
  register: result
  until: not result.rc  # or result.rc == 0 if you prefer
  retries: 20
  delay: 3
```

This runs `mysqladmin ping ...` until it succeeds (return code 0). Usually superuser is `root`. I tested using podman instead of docker but I believe the command is the same regardless. `|quote` does shell escaping, which [according to the Ansible docs](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/modules/command_module.html#examples) should also be done when using `command:`

Comment: Is there a version of this that does not require the root MySQL user?

Comment: @JeroenDeDauw I'm not sure whether I've tried running it with a regular user, it might just work. If not, you could try calling `SELECT 1;` with `mysql` instead.

Answer (score 3):

This works for me just fine:

```
  - name: get mariadb IP address
    command: "docker inspect --format '{''{ .NetworkSettings.IPAddress }''}' mariadb-container"
    register: mariadb_ip_address
  - name: wait for mariadb to become ready
    wait_for:
      host: "{{ mariadb_ip_address.stdout }}"
      port: 3306
      state: started
      delay: 5
      connect_timeout: 15
      timeout: 30
```

Answer (score 1):

Use [**`wait_for`**](http://docs.ansible.com/wait_for_module.html) module. I'm no expert on MySQL but I assume there would be some port or existence of file or message in some log file etc. you can check to find out if the DB is up or not.

Here are examples of `wait_for` copied from the link above.

```
# wait 300 seconds for port 8000 to become open on the host, don't start checking for 10 seconds
- wait_for: port=8000 delay=10

# wait 300 seconds for port 8000 of any IP to close active connections, don't start checking for 10 seconds
- wait_for: host=0.0.0.0 port=8000 delay=10 state=drained

# wait 300 seconds for port 8000 of any IP to close active connections, ignoring connections for specified hosts
- wait_for: host=0.0.0.0 port=8000 state=drained exclude_hosts=10.2.1.2,10.2.1.3

# wait until the file /tmp/foo is present before continuing
- wait_for: path=/tmp/foo

# wait until the string "completed" is in the file /tmp/foo before continuing
- wait_for: path=/tmp/foo search_regex=completed

# wait until the lock file is removed
- wait_for: path=/var/lock/file.lock state=absent

# wait until the process is finished and pid was destroyed
- wait_for: path=/proc/3466/status state=absent

# wait 300 seconds for port 22 to become open and contain "OpenSSH", don't assume the inventory_hostname is resolvable
# and don't start checking for 10 seconds
- local_action: wait_for port=22 host="{{ ansible_ssh_host | default(inventory_hostname) }}" search_regex=OpenSSH delay=10
```

Comment: While I too believe ```wait_for``` to be the right answer this leads to another problem: How to figure out the IP Address of the docker container? The database container does not bind to a port on the localhost so to wait for it to start, we would need the IP address assigned to the container by docker. I am currently to get the IP using ```docker inspect``` but this does not yet provide results.

Comment: @Tobias perhaps posting a new question with appropriate details would help.

Answer (score 1):

I was able to use wait_for like this:

```
    - name: "MySQL - Check mysql - Wait for mysql to be up"
      wait_for:
        host: 127.0.0.1
        port: 3306
        search_regex: "(mysql_native_password|caching_sha2_password)"
```

This way it will wait for the port o be up and for the service to send some data.

The drawback is that the output may change with mysql versions and configurations. In the example are the strings for mysql 5.5 and 8.0. Adjust for your use cases.

An alternative, avoiding running *wait_for*, *command* or *shell*, may be to retry some mysql command several times until it succedes:

```
    - name: "MySQL - Check mysql - if it responds"
      mysql_info:
        login_user: root
        login_password: "{{ mysql_root_password }}"
        filter:
          - version
      register: mysql_result
      until: mysql_result is not failed
      retries: 5
      delay: 10
```